# GitHub parse issue body as a file and extract specific line to a variable

Tags: bash, github-actions

Need workflow to Read GitHub Issue body as a file and parse line by line to get package name and version from the issue body and store in two different variables and copy these two variables into package.json file in JSON format.

Issue looks like this:

```
Issue to pull husky package #1

Package Name
husky

Package Version
4.3.8

Purpose
test-purpose

Maintainer Team
abc
```

Now from the above Issue body, after getting the "/approve" in the comment section, workflow is triggered to install the required NPM package

Tried to print the issue body based on the comment as mentioned below:

```yaml
name: check_issue_approval
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [opened, edited]

env:
  PKG_VER: ${{ github.event.issue.title }}
  
jobs:
 check_issue_approval:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: contains(github.event.comment.body, '/approve')
    outputs: 
      approved: ${{ steps.check-approval.outputs.approved }}
    
  steps:
   - name: Check required package
     run: |
        while IFS="" read -r line ||  [ -n "$line" ]
          echo "Checking $BODY file for the required package and version"
           do
              # cat "$BODY" > "$line"
              if ( "$line" eq "Package Name" )
                then
                    echo "$line"
              fi
           done <"$BODY" 
  env:
    BODY: ${{ github.event.issue.body }}

   - name: Install and Upload required NPM package from Issue into Jfrog Artifactory
        run: |
           T="${{ env.PKG_VER }}"  # T means Issue Title
           S="${T##* }"
           IFS=','
           read -ra arr <<< "$S"
           for val in "${arr[@]}";
           do
             printf "name = $val\n"
             npm install --registry local-registry "$val"
           done
```

I am able to print the complete issue body but unable to fetch only the package name and version as they are in the different lines to store them in separate variables and can use them as input variables in the command like: `npm i $first@$second` meaning `npm i husky@4.3.8`.

Please let me know how to get only the pkg name and version from the issue body as separate variables.

Comment: And how did your attempt not get you what you wanted? What did you expect, what did you get instead?

Comment: I am able to print complete issue body but unable to fetch only the package name and version as they are in the different lines to store them in variables to use them in the command like:  npm i husky@4.3.8

Comment: You can iterate line by line and extract the required values to variables using Bash. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-can-i-read-line-by-line-from-a-variable-in-bash.

Comment: Tried these:                                                                                                                        `  - name: Check required package
        run: |
            while IFS="" read -r line ||  [ -n "$line" ]
            echo "Checking $BODY file for the required package and version"
            do
               cat "$BODY" > "$line"
            done <"$BODY"

Comment: Also I have tried these:           cat "$BODY" | grep -o '".*"' | sed 1d | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/\^//g' | awk -F': ' '{ print $1"@"$2 }' > "pkg"
          echo "pkg"
          for p in pkg 
          do 
              npm install p
          done `

Comment: Please update your question with these attempts formatted in codeblocks. Thanks!

Comment: I just formatted the issue body. Could you please verify if that's what it looks like?

Comment: Thanks! Azeem for the issue -body format change.

Comment: Getting: 
Annotations
1 error
check-issue
Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: @Raghu: As you're using JavaScript and need to set `package.json`, why don't you simply use it (JavaScript) for this also? What do you think?

Comment: @Azeem, sorry I was not keeping well and couldn't reply, am not using JScript to get the content of ISSUE body, instead I am using shell commands in the loop in YAML GitHub workflow, so if you have any shortcuts in JScript and that can be used in YAML format, please do let me know. I am trying to get the line of the PKG name and version from ISSUE body and based on ISSUE comment  (/approve) the workflow has to trigger the event. And finally if this works, copy PKG-NAME and PKG-VERSION from ISSUE into package.json file. Hope it is clear now?

Comment: @Raghu: No worries. Hope you're feeling better now! I thought you were using JS due to those `npm` commands in your workflow. Your format is very specific and I'm not aware of some generic action that does that. Your best bet is to parse it yourself with Bash or JS (if it's the tech stack that project is in).

Answer (score 0):

Learnt from my friend that if the PKG-NAME@version is mentioned in the issue title it is easy to fetch the info into a variable ("$val") and pull into workflow, which was accepted by customer and so the logic is changed in the workflow to fetch the pkg-name and version in a variable $val and pull that variable to install using npm install command into Jfrog registry. This works!  Thankyou all for your support/suggestion.

Here are the changes in the requirement.
So my issue title would be:
Issue to pull NPM packages: husky@4.3.8,eslint@8.23.0,semver@6.3.0
Now all I need to do is to get the pkg@version from issue, install and upload into Jfrog repository.

Thanks again!